# URL redirect if contains a word

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

how I can redirect per htaccess all URLs what contains a specific word

For example:

```
http://videos.showtime.com.ph/its-showtime-hashtag-boys-macho-dance_03be98da6.html
```

should be redirected to:

```
http://showtime.com.ph
```

The specific word should be `its-showtime`. All URls where `its-showtime` is inside should be redirected.

I tried already something around but is doesn't work.

**Update:** Existing .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.showtime\.com\.ph$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ showtime\.com\.ph/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

---

**SOLVED:** https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/88435/how-to-redirect-url-with-specific-characters/88440?noredirect=1#comment108357_88440

Answer (score 0):

You can use that in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule its-showtime http://showtime.com.ph [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but unfortunately this doesn't work. I put your code in my .htaccess and also in the .conf

Also i tried it like this:

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule its-showtime http://showtime.\.com\.ph/$1 [NC,R=301,L]

Comment: Nothing else in your .htaccess?

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.showtime\.com\.ph$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://showtime\.com\.ph/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}